# rails setting form_for id attribute causes: Couldn't find Folder with 'id'=add_client

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a form_for that looks as follows:

```
  <div class="modal-body">
    <%= form_for @folder, url: add_client_folders_path, html: { id: "add_client" }   do |f| %>
      <%= f.fields_for :client_profiles do |client_builder| %>
          <%= client_builder.select :id, @clients.collect {|client| [ client.name, client.id ] }, { include_blank: true }, {class: "form-control"} %>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <%= submit_tag "Add Client", class: "btn btn-primary", form: "add_client" %>
  </div>
```

When the form is submitted the params hash looks like this:

Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"7qxjMI1H/+uMP4qZWwG4lHxdrBBM1z", "folder"=>{"client_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"id"=>"25"}}}, "commit"=>"Add Client", "id"=>"add_client"}

It gives me the below error:

```
Couldn't find Folder with 'id'=add_client
```

Why is Rails submitting the html id attribute in hash causing this error?

Even when I remove the id it is still giving me this error. Route looks like this:

```
  resources :folders do
    post :add_client, on: :collection
  end
```

When I explicitly declare post method, it submits fine:

```
method: :post
```

But why must I specify method post here?

Comment: I think the problem was @folder was an existing record, so it tried to convert the method to put, which caused that error.

Answer (score 0):

For future readers, I have a better idea than creating a separate resource route. You can continue to reuse the update restful resource because the new association will be saved automatically when you update the existing record:

```
 <%= form_for @folder do |f| %>
   <%= f.fields_for :client_profiles, f.object.client_profiles.build do |client_builder| %>
     <%= client_builder.select :id, @clients.collect {|client| [ client.full_name, client.id ] }, { include_blank: true }, {class: "form-control"} %>
      <%= f.submit "Add Client", class: "btn btn-primary" %
```

>